# Bot c#: How can I reconnect to old conversation with direct line

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm using WebChat DirectLine to integrate my Bot into xamarine app, but I don't know if I can load old conversations which I store into DB before user types anything new. Also how can I get the userID from directline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your database structure but if you save the conversation id and datetime of all messages you can easily select the last x messages in a chronological order.

As for you userID, You will have to generate and save that yourself in your Xamarin Application. This is a value that the bot expects to get from the Channel or the connector.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I know when the user opens the chat to load the old conversations?

Comment: Well, it's your own Xamarin app, no? You can do that when your load the conversation screen. In the constructor for example or the `OnAppearing` eventhandler.

Comment: And how to make it to look like real conversation bot-user? Because when I load from db messages always appears on bots side.

Comment: You add an extra column to your table specifying if the person/bot that send the message.